# Can Python 3 react to opened files on my mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to have a python program react to an opened file?  For example, can I get it to do something when I open a text file or another python file?

Comment: You want a running python script to do something when you open a certain type of file?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is No.

The long answer is: It depends on what you mean by "open"—but for most reasonable definitions, on any modern macOS, it will be doable, but difficult, and will likely break in 10.14 or 10.15.

---

For example, let's say you're looking to hook every POSIX-level `open` by any process on the system. The `DTrace` API provides a way to do that. But if you try to use it:

```
$ sudo dtruss -t open_noncancel -f -p 1
```

… if you're on 10.9 or later, you'll see a message like this:

```
dtrace: system integrity protection is on, some features will not be available
```

And then, when someone opens a file, you'll either see nothing at all, or, at best, a string of errors like this:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 123 (ID 456: syscall::thread_selfid:entry): invalid user access in action #2 at DIF offset 0
```

You can read about [SIP (System Integrity Protection) Runtime Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH3-SW1) here, or on various third-party blog posts like [this one](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2015/10/01/system-integrity-protection-adding-another-layer-to-apples-security-model/), but in recent versions of OS X, there's basically no way to disable it except in recovery mode without some major hackery.

---

Is there any way to get around it? For specific limited uses, yes. While that `dtruss` command above doesn't work, you can do this:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/filebyproc.d
```

Or even this:

```
$ sudo dtrace -n 'syscall::open*:entry { printf("%s %s", execname, copyinstr(arg0)); }'
```

… and you could replace that `printf` with code that executes your Python script, instead of trying to run this in a `subprocess` and parse its output.

And you *will* get output… but not for all processes.

On 10.13, all processes that are specifically blacklisted by SIP won't show up at all. And sandboxed apps—which includes things like TextEdit, and everything you can install off the App Store—will only show files inside their own sandbox, not files you pass them explicitly. Which makes it a lot less useful.

---

What about getting around it in general? Well, then you're basically asking how to write a rootkit. Find some exploit in SIP/Darwin/Mach, do a lot of complicated work to take advantage of it, and then when 10.14 comes out, start all over again because Apple closed the exploit.

Answer (score 0):

You can get alerts on create, delete, modify and move of directories / files using tools like `inotify`, `fswatch` (for OSX) or `watchdog`. However I'm not aware of a way to get an alert on a file open in the general case. You'd probably need to use `lsof`, or do what lsof does for you: scan through `/proc/*/fs` - polling, not an event-driven approach which is what it sounds like you want.

Comment: The OP is on a Mac. `inotify`, the `/proc` filesystem, etc. are Linux-specific things.